How to close minimap in monaco diff editor
I dont want the right minimap, and my code is
const original = [
    '#include <iostream>',
    'using namespace std;',
    'int main()',
    '{',
    '    cout << \\"Hello, world!\\" << endl;',
  ];
const  modified = [
      '#include<iostream>',
      '',
      'int main()',
      '{',
      '    std::cout << \\"Hello, world!\\"<< std::endl;'
  ];
// Hover on each property to see its docs!
const myEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById("container"), {
    originalEditable: true,
    renderIndicators: true,
    minimap: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    contextmenu: true,
});
myEditor.setModel({
    original: monaco.editor.createModel(original.join('\n')),
    modified: monaco.editor.createModel(modified.join('\n')),
});
myEditor.updateOptions({
  minimap: {
    enabled: false,
  },
});

but i can't close the minimap.
enter image description here
please help me to close the right minimap

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The bit you're referring to in the screenshot is the "overview ruler". You can remove this by setting the option renderOverviewRuler: false
If you also want to remove vertical bit to the left of that (that contains the black horizontal line in your screenshot) you can set the option: overviewRulerLanes: 0
Here's a working demo in the Monaco Playground.
